# HTML5 datalist tag is not working in android

Tags: android, html, webview, cordova

I am using the datalist tag to provide  auto-complete to an input text. The tag is working fine on desktop chrome but it's not working when I test it on my phone( Android) 
can any one help ? 
If not can you suggest a way to do auto-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/datalist check here,
android browser not supports. so you have use jquerymobile or other framework.

Answer (score 2):

Android browser is a webKit-based browser so it does not support Datalist tag therefore it ignores the code that is included in the Datalist tag. This is the case in most old browsers.

A small work-around you can use is to embed the `select` tag inside `datalist` tag. The browsers that support `datalist` will ignore the `select` tag, but the browsers that don't support will display a dropdown just below the input box. You can handle the `onchange` event of the `select` as shown below to fill the value in the input box when the user selects it.

```
    <input type="text" id="country-input" list="countryList">
    <datalist id="countryList">
       <select onchange="$('#country-input').val(this.value)">
        <option label="India" value="IN"></option>
        <option label="United Stated" value="USA"></option>
        <option label="United Kingdom" value="UK"></option>
        <option label="Brazil" value="BRA"></option>
        <option label="Russia" value="RUS"></option>
       </select>
    </datalist>
```

PS: The jquery code inside `onchange` is just an example, you'll need to modify it based on your implementation.

<strike>See a small solution [HERE](http://devproconnections.com/html5/working-html5-web-forms-autocompletion-and-datalist-element)! (in section Datalist for old browsers), hope it will work for you.</strike>

Comment: It works in the browsers even IE but it didn't work on the mobile :S

Comment: The link is broken here.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Please fix

Comment: @Ajji: shared another solution, hopefully that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 datalist does not work in Chrome 96 on Android on HTTP connections. Works on HTTPS connections.

Tested localy.

Can be checked with HTTPS here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist